# problem with a submit and last powerApps 's folder modified in my APP

Tags: submit, form-submit, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am currently building an app with PowerApps, but i have a problem...

In fact, i would like that **my app be on several screens**. So in the first edit screen i use a button with the following formula :

**Patch(NAME_OF_MY_SHAREPOINT_LIST,First(Filter(NAME_OF_MY_SHAREPOINT_LIST,ID = idcourant )),{balise:idcourant});SubmitForm(EditForm1);EditForm(EditForm1_1);Navigate(EditScreen1_1)**

So i create and use a variable **(idcourant)** to modify the current folder which is the first edit screen **(EditForm1)** and i put this variable in the field **"balise"**[image]. In fact the problem is when i click on the button : the application put the user on the last modified and recorded folder of the list SharePoint...So the current folder change of ID, and this is another folder with another ID which is opended in the second edit screen:**(EditForm1_1)**. This is a big problem for me because my application is not available for the moment and i must to deploy it very soon.... Are there any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact i have found a solution : Make a submit of the first form, and then go to the next edit form.... It was so easy ... lol

SubmitForm(EditForm1);EditForm(EditForm1_1);Navigate(EditForm1_1)